# GnuPG: Plugin for Outlook that allows searching through encrypted mails

Tags: email, encryption, outlook

I have tested `gpg4win` as a plugin for Outlook. But when I use that I cannot use Outlook to search for body text in the email.

I imagine it is due to the email being encrypted and that Outlook searches through the encrypted email and not the decrypted email.

My threat model is to protect the email transfer. As soon as the email hits our mailserver we consider it safe to store decrypted. So I imagine a solution would be for `gpg4win` to decrypt the email using my passphrase and then store the decrypted version back on the system and my local cache, which can then be searched as an ordinary email.

Is there a way I can search through encrypted emails using Outlook?

Comment: So what are you trying to do? Decrypt messages to let Outlook index them? Or make Outlook index encrypted messages?

Comment: I am trying to get a setup where the encryption is transparent to the users: Searching should work just as well on encrypted mail as on unencrypted mail.

Comment: Yes, and what are you trying to do to achieve that? Decrypt the messages or somehow make Outlook process encrypted messages?

Comment: I am open for any solution. The one solution I could imagine was the one where Outlook decrypts the message when the user opens it, and then Outlook saves the decrypted mail back to be indexed. I, however, do not know how to make Outlook do this. Other solutions that solve the searching problem are welcome.

Comment: What decrypts the message? Outlook? Or the gpg4win addin?

Comment: As it is now: The gpg4win plugin in Outlook. But I am open for other solutions.

Comment: So can you programmatically decrypt the message?

Comment: gpg4win decrypts the email when it is opened by the user. But even after it has been opened it is still not searchable. This leads me to believe the decrypted version is discarded when the user closes this again.

Answer (score 0):

Ole,
you should give gp4o a try. [gpg4o](http://www.gpg4o.com)
If you want you can save the mail after decryption, so it can be processed by the indexer. Additionally it is the easiest PGP plugin I have discovered

Best regards
Karl